# How to make ajax call using jquery each for each input type files in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having a simple form with one input for single file and another input for multiple files how can I make ajax call looping file by file and along with other form data each time?

```
<form id = "uploadForm" name = "uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="uploadFile">Upload Your File</label>
    <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile">
    <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachments" multiple />

    <input type="text" name="attachmentId" value="1236"> 
    <input type="text" name="attachmentName" > 
    <input type="text" name="JobId" value="xyz" >
    <input type="text" name="fileCategory" value="abc">
```

Right now I am doing whole ajax Form submit like below:

```
$('#'+formId).ajaxForm({
    url:FileUploadUrl,
    headers: { "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest" },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType:'json',
    success : function(data){
},
```

But I want to do it for one file at a time, Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "other form data"? Are you trying to make an a `POST` request for each file object?

Answer (score 0):

Not certain what purpose is for calling `$.ajax()` for each `File` object,  though you can use `$.when()`, `Function.prototype.apply()`, `$.map()`, `.map()` to perform request for each `File` at `input type="file"` `FileList` at `.files` property

```
var n = 0;
var requests = $.when.apply($, $.map($("#uploadForm :file"), function(input) {
  return $.when.apply($, [].slice.call(input.files).map(function(file, index) { 
             return $.ajax({url, data:new FormData("file-" + n++, file)})
           })
         )
}))
.then(function(results) {
     console.log(results)
}, function handleErr(err) {
     console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: hi @guest271314, But in my case I need to submit my form with only 1 file at a time reason serverside code is expecting all in FormDataParams:

Comment: <input type="text" name="attachmentId" value="{{properties.attachmentId}}" style="display:none">
                    <input type="text" name="attachmentName"  style="display:none">
                    <input type="text" name="JobId" value="{{properties.ccr.value}}" style="display:none">
                    <input type="text" name="fileCategory" value="{{properties.fileCategory}}" style="display:none">       ..............I have these other inputs to send along with 1 file at a time

Comment: _"But in my case I need to submit my form with only 1 file at a time"_ `javascript` at Question posts one file at each `$.ajax()` request. Are you trying to append all files to single `FormData` instance?

Comment: please see above I have updated my form code along with file inputs I have other data that I need to send as part of form data file by file any ideas for that?

Comment: Are you trying to send the same form fields with each file, or only once?